# Stopping Condition Dilemma: ODE Integration with C++ and Boost Library

Tags: c++, boost, ode, odeint

I am currently working on solving an ordinary differential equation (ODE) using C++ and the Boost library. The specific form of the ODE is dp/dt = (...) with an initial condition of p(0) = pmax. The task at hand is to design an integrator that halts when the condition p(r) <= p_min is met. However, the challenge lies in the fact that I don't have prior knowledge of the exact value for end_time, as the integrator receives input values such as "start_time," "end_time," and "dt."

Comment: this seems to be a question about maths not about programming or c++ specifically

Comment: This is a numerical mathematics question. You should also find an appropiate algorithm for solving your equation with the smallest (accumulated) error.

Comment: You can call your integrator in a loop, doing just one timestep at a time and testing for p(r) < pmin in YOUR loop, rather than the integrator's. If you find that inefficient then you can ESTIMATE the time required simply from t = (p(target)-p(current))/dpdt(current) and take, say, half of that at each pass of your loop.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You want to implement event handling, with the root function `p-p_min`, the graph passing zero downwards at the desired root, and triggering a "terminate" action. The usual implementation is to use the "dense output" interpolation in each step and search (coarsely) for sign changes of the root function in the interval of the step, then use Brent or some other bracketing root finder to locate the root exactly. Matlab and scipy's solve_ivp among others (R desolve, julia diffeq) implement such.